# TF 2.0 Keras fit_generator: data_generator outputs wrong shape

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm trying to train an image captioning model using **TensorFlow 2.0** and **tf.keras** API. The dataset I'm using is the Flickr 8K dataset and although my computer can hold the entire dataset in RAM I'd like to use fit_generator with a data_generator to load and prepare data by batch (because once I can make it work with this dataset I'll try to train this model with a larger dataset).

The way I'm pre-processing the data and the model definition are OK. I can do model.predict() on a manually generated batch and the model outputs the expected data shape and no errors. I can also use the data_generator manually to prepare the full dataset and use the whole data with **model.fit()** and it works, the model trains with no error.

The problem comes when I try to train using **fit_generator**, that will output this error *(full length error output at the end of the post)*:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (168,2048) into shape (168)
```

If I call the generator function alone to check type and shape of the generated batch, it seems to me that everything is ok:

```
generator = data_generator(train_descriptions, train_features, wordtoix, max_length, number_pics_per_bath)
data = next(generator)

print("Total items in data: ", len(data))

# Data[1] is the encoded Y
print("Encodded Y shape: ", data[1].shape)
print("Example Y: ", data[1][0])

# Data[0] is a list of [image_feature, encoded_caption]
print("X1 shape (image feature): ", data[0][0].shape)
print("X2 shape (image caption): ", data[0][1].shape)

Outputs:
    -----------------------------------
    Total items in data:  2
    Encodded Y shape:  (168, 1652)
    Example Y:  [0. 0. 1. ... 0. 0. 0.]
    X1 shape (image feature):  (168, 2048)
    X2 shape (image caption):  (168, 34)
```

This is the code of the **data_generator** function:

```
# data generator, intended to be used in a call to model.fit_generator()
# $descriptions: a dictionary containing <image_id> -> [ text_captions_list ]
# photos: list of numpy arrays representing image features
# wordtoix: a dictionary to convert words to word_codes (integers)
# max_length: maximum word count for a caption
def data_generator(descriptions, photos, wordtoix, max_length, num_photos_per_batch):
    X1, X2, y = list(), list(), list()
    n=0
    # loop for ever over images
    while 1:
        for key, desc_list in descriptions.items():
            n+=1
            # retrieve the photo feature
            photo = photos[key+'.jpg']
            for desc in desc_list:
                # encode the sequence
                seq = [wordtoix[word] for word in desc.split(' ') if word in wordtoix]
                # split one sequence into multiple X, y pairs
                for i in range(1, len(seq)):
                    # split into input and output pair
                    in_seq, out_seq = seq[:i], seq[i]
                    # pad input sequence
                    in_seq = pad_sequences([in_seq], maxlen=max_length)[0]
                    # encode output sequence
                    out_seq = to_categorical([out_seq], num_classes=vocab_size)[0]
                    # store
                    X1.append(photo)
                    X2.append(in_seq)
                    y.append(out_seq)
            # yield the batch data
            if n==num_photos_per_batch:
                yield [[array(X1), array(X2)], array(y)]

                X1, X2, y = list(), list(), list()
                n=0
```

And this is how I'm calling **fit_generator**:

```
epochs = 20
steps = len(train_descriptions)
for i in range(epochs):
    generator = data_generator(train_descriptions, train_features, wordtoix, max_length)
    model.fit_generator(generator, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=steps, verbose=1)
    model.save('./saved/model_' + str(i) + '.h5')
for i in range(epochs):
    generator = data_generator(train_descriptions, train_features, wordtoix, max_length, number_pics_per_bath)
    model.fit_generator(generator, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=steps, verbose=1)
    model.save('./saved/model_' + str(i) + '.h5')
```

I'm using the **inceptionv3** model with imagenet pre-trained weights to generate features from images (that are then saved to disk).

Then I use this model assembly that expects "two inputs": an image *feature* array and an encoded image *caption*:

```
inputs1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(2048,))
fe1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(inputs1)
fe2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(fe1)

inputs2 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(max_length,))
se1 = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, mask_zero=True)(inputs2)
se2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(se1)
se3 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(256)(se2)

decoder1 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([fe2, se3])
decoder2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(decoder1)

outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')(decoder2)

model = Model(inputs=[inputs1, inputs2], outputs=outputs)
```

The full length error from fit_generator is the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-10ea3905954d> in <module>
      1 for i in range(epochs):
      2     generator = data_generator(train_descriptions, train_features, wordtoix, max_length, number_pics_per_bath)
----> 3     model.fit_generator(generator, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=steps, verbose=1)
      4     model.save('./saved/model_' + str(i) + '.h5')

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1295         shuffle=shuffle,
   1296         initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
-> 1297         steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
   1298 
   1299   def evaluate_generator(self,

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_generator.py in model_iteration(model, data, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch, mode, batch_size, steps_name, **kwargs)
    263 
    264       is_deferred = not model._is_compiled
--> 265       batch_outs = batch_function(*batch_data)
    266       if not isinstance(batch_outs, list):
    267         batch_outs = [batch_outs]

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in train_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, reset_metrics)
    971       outputs = training_v2_utils.train_on_batch(
    972           self, x, y=y, sample_weight=sample_weight,
--> 973           class_weight=class_weight, reset_metrics=reset_metrics)
    974       outputs = (outputs['total_loss'] + outputs['output_losses'] +
    975                  outputs['metrics'])

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py in train_on_batch(model, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, reset_metrics)
    251   x, y, sample_weights = model._standardize_user_data(
    252       x, y, sample_weight=sample_weight, class_weight=class_weight,
--> 253       extract_tensors_from_dataset=True)
    254   batch_size = array_ops.shape(nest.flatten(x, expand_composites=True)[0])[0]
    255   # If `model._distribution_strategy` is True, then we are in a replica context

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, batch_size, check_steps, steps_name, steps, validation_split, shuffle, extract_tensors_from_dataset)
   2470           feed_input_shapes,
   2471           check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
-> 2472           exception_prefix='input')
   2473 
   2474     # Get typespecs for the input data and sanitize it if necessary.

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    504   elif isinstance(data, (list, tuple)):
    505     if isinstance(data[0], (list, tuple)):
--> 506       data = [np.asarray(d) for d in data]
    507     elif len(names) == 1 and isinstance(data[0], (float, int)):
    508       data = [np.asarray(data)]

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    504   elif isinstance(data, (list, tuple)):
    505     if isinstance(data[0], (list, tuple)):
--> 506       data = [np.asarray(d) for d in data]
    507     elif len(names) == 1 and isinstance(data[0], (float, int)):
    508       data = [np.asarray(data)]

~/anaconda3/envs/tf2-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     83 
     84     """
---> 85     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     86 
     87 

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (168,2048) into shape (168)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Having the same problem, did you solve it finally?

Comment: Not yet, I moved from the Keras approach to a more pure TF 2.0 approach (using tf.data.Dataset for batching instead of data generators) and is working just fine. I'm preparing some Jupiter notebooks now, I will share them once finished, but meanwhile I would recommend you check the TF2.0 examples of encoder-decoder for image captioning and language translation as a kick-starter.

Answer (score -1):

There should be a return statement for def data_generator. That worked for me TBH!
incase: https://github.com/santoshgopane/Automatic-image-Captioning-using-RNN

Comment: Generators do not require return statements

Comment: I have updated my answer. have a look. 